# Mapping $ [0,1] $ to Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

We learned about a function as follows:

Any number $x$ in $[0,1]$ has a binary expansion $x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e_n}{2^n}$.   Let the function $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2e_n}{3^n}$.

This function is mapping to the Cantor set, because the ternary expansion of $g(x)$ for any $x$ will not have 1 in it.  We were told it is continuous except at points $p/2^n$, where $p$ and $n$ are integers.  I am having trouble wrapping my head around this function, and particularly its points of discontinuity.  Here are some examples (subscript denotes the kind of expansion, i.e. $0.5_2$ is binary expansion.)

If $x=0.9_{10}=0.111001100..._{2}$, so $g(x) = 0.222002200..._{3}$.  Since $.9$ cannot be expressed as $p/2^n$, then it is continuous here.

However, at $x=0.5 = 0.1_{2}$, so $g(x) = 0.2_3$.  It is not continuous here.

Essentially, it is continuous for $x$ which can be written as an binary expansion that terminates (i.e. is not infinite like for $0.9$).  Could you please help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)$ is **continues** at $x$ if and only if $x$ has **infinite** binary expansion( has finite $1$ in binary expansion e.g $0.9$).
Because $g$ is a [locally constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_constant_function), and jump when $x$ has finite binary expansion (like $0.5$).
Here is the plot of this function by Mathematica : 
[image]

Of course the vertical lines are fake! They are occurred in the jumping points.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta >0$. Observe that we can always find an $x\in (\frac{1}{2^{n}}-\delta ,\frac{1}{2^{n}})$ s.t. $g(x)\leq \frac{2}{3^{n}}$.On the other hand, there is always a $y\in (\frac{1}{2^{n}},\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\delta)$ s.t. $g(y)\geq \frac{2}{3^{n-1}}$. Thus, $g$ has a jump discontinuity at each $r=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$.

It is easy to see now that $g$ is discontinuous at each dyadic rational in $[0,1].$